# Protractor - wait after switch to window or iframe

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, wait, end-to-end

I'm trying to replace 'timeouts' or 'Sleeps' with 'wait' for the test to be faster. I was not able to find the right way to wait for switching to window or iframe that doesn't have identifier.

For example:

```
browser.sleep(5000);
browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]).then(function() {
    // login.logout();
});
```

and:

```
flow.timeout(5000);

browser.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently solved something quite similar with a *custom [Expected Condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions)* that *checks for a specified number of window handles*:

```
function windowCount (count) {
    return function () {
        return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            return handles.length === count;
        });
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
browser.wait(windowCount(2), 5000);
```

Comment: @user2880391 I think you can just wait for the presence of the `iframe` element: `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.tagName("iframe"))), 5000)` where `EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions`. Hope it works for you too.